# Find all product ID from array of customfield

Tags: wp-query

I need to get product ID from an array of custom field, I have this code to find all product with the same custom field, after deleting all duplicate custom field value, I need to retrieve product id for all custom field:

```
<?php
// Get all product cip by category
$product_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'no_found_rows' => true,  // Skips SQL to count rows - a speed improvement.
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,  // Don't move sticky posts to top - a speed improvement.
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids',  // Only return product IDs
);

if (!empty($str_ArrayChild))
{
    $product_args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $str_ArrayChild,
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ));
}

$products = get_posts($product_args);

// Search CIP by product ID
foreach ( $products as $id )
{
    $cip = $product_obj['product_cip']=get_post_meta($id,'product_cip');
    //echo 'Cip = '.$cip[0].', ';

    $arrayCip[] = $cip[0];
}

echo '<b>TotalNumberOfCIP = '.count($arrayCip).'</b>';

// Remove same cip
$result = array_unique($arrayCip);

//print_r($result);
echo '<b>TotalNumberOfUniqueCIP = '.count($result).'</b>';

// trace Unique Cip list
/*foreach ($arrayCip as $v)
{
    echo $v;
}
```

Here I need to find all ID's of `$arrayCip` (customfield named `product_cip`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$product = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'product_cip',
            'value' => 'some value',
            'compare' => '=',
        )
    ),
    'fields' => 'ids',
);


$product_post = get_posts($product);
echo count($product_post);
```

if you have get all products data

```
$products_array = array();
foreach ($product_post as $v){
    $_product = wc_get_product($v);
    echo $_product->get_name().',';
    $products_array[] = $_product;
}
```

Comment: thanks but I already find the duplicated customfield, My need is to find product ID based on $result that is an array of cutomfield. after : $result = array_unique($arrayCip); find product id from $result

Answer (score 0):

Ok founded!

```
foreach ($result as $v)
                            {
                                $product=array(
                                    'post_type' => 'product',
                                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                                    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
                                    'meta_query' => array(
                                        array( 'key' =>
                                            'product_cip',
                                            'value' => $v,
                                            'compare'=> '=' ) ),
                                    'fields' => 'ids'
                                );
                                $product_post=get_posts($product);
                                //echo $product_post[0].', ';
                                $a[] = $product_post[0];
                                //echo count($product_post);
                            }
                            //echo ' ProductID count = '.count($a).' ';

                            // If products exist, show products
                            if(count($a) > 0)
                            {
                                $productArrayForShortcode = implode(",", $a);
                                echo do_shortcode('[products ids="' . $productArrayForShortcode . '" per_page="8" columns="4" pagination="true"]');
                            }
```

Thanks for the tip @Dharmishtha